# Share a piece of Redux state with custom functions only when its value has become stable

Tags: redux, react-redux, office-js, custom-functions-excel

We have an add-in built with ReactJS, redux, and redux-saga. Now, we are adding custom functions to the add-in. In our manifest, we have the following setting, where `Functions.Taskpane.Url` points to a webpage `ourdomain.com/#/functions`.

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
    <Script>
    <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url"/>
    </Script>
    <Page>
    <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Taskpane.Url"/>
    </Page>
    <Metadata>
    <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url"/>
    </Metadata>
    <Namespace resid="Functions.Namespace"/>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

The page `ourdomain.com/#/functions` is built with ReactJS and Redux. It's like

```
declare var OfficeRuntime;

interface FunctionsStartProps {
  settings: any
}

const FunctionsStart: React.FunctionComponent<FunctionsStartProps> = ({ settings }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    OfficeRuntime.storage.setItem("shared-settings", JSON.stringify(settings))
      .then(() => { console.log("settings updated in OfficeRuntime.storage by FunctionsStart") })
      .catch((error) => { console.error("Error updating settings in OfficeRuntime.storage by FunctionsStart:", error) });
  }, [settings]);

  return (<div></div>)
}

export default withTranslation()(connect((state: ReduxState) => ({
  settings: selectors.settings.getSettings(state)
}))(FunctionsStart));
```

Inside a custom function `f`, we use `OfficeRuntime.storage.getItem("shared-settings")` to get the value of `settings`.

When the component `FunctionsStart` is loaded, `settings` in the Redux store first has `initialValue`, then it quickly changes to `stableValue`. Our tests show that the first time we run the function `f` (which triggers the loading of `FunctionsStart`), the value of `settings` is `initialValue`; the second (and following) time we run the function `f`, the value of `settings` is `stableValue`.

However, what we would like to achieve is that inside the function `f`, we always get `stableValue`, even from the first time of the execution. We would like to run the body of the function `f` only after the properties of `FunctionsStart` has become stable.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. If the "stable value" is *always* set later *after* the component mounts, then the component will *always* have the "initial value" from the initial render and any subsequent renders until the Redux state is updated with the "stable value". The React code should be capable of handling this while "data is loaded".